# javascript regex replace nonwords and spaces does not work?

Tags: javascript, regex, space

```
var st = "Dream Theater A Change of Seasons (EP) (1995)";
var searchTerm = st.replace("/[\s\W]+/g", "+");
```

gives 
`Dream Theater A Change of Seasons EP 1995`

but I want to be
`Dream+Theater+A+Change+of+Seasons+EP+1995+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

`st.replace(/\s/g, "+");`

which just replaces every whitespace char with a `+`.  Also note I removed the quotes around the regex -- you want a regex, not a string.

EDIT -- Just tried

`st.replace(/[\s\W]+/g, "+"); // no quotes around the regex`

and that gives you the `+` on the end.  So the real problem is you are passing a string when you want to pass an actual regex reference.

Answer (score 2):

You need:

```
var searchTerm = st.replace(/[\s\W]+/g, "+");
```

without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
var searchTerm = st.replace(/[\s\W]+/g, '+');
```